# DataGridListView's SelectedItem null in MVVM after binding WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, visual-studio, data-binding

i'm having some troubles with databinding of selecteditem of a datagridlistview.
I implemented an event on doubleclick with a command and commandparameter.
I'd like to pass as command parameter the row that i double clicked (the selected item).

I tried this:

```
   <ui:DataGridListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="6" MinHeight="200"
                         Name="PTest"                          
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource model}, Path=EsecuzioniCollection}"
                         VisibleItems="{Binding Source={StaticResource model}, Path=VisibleItems, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource model}, Path= SelectedItem}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource model}, Path=MouseDoubleClickCommand}">
                </i:InvokeCommandAction>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        ...............
</ui:DataGridListView>
```

But when command is invoked the parameter SelectedItem is null:

```
 public async void MouseDoubleClick(PerimetriTestDataItem item)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I tried also putting SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem} on ui:DataGridListView but it's null on my viewmodel.

Is there a way to bind the row? any tricks?

Thank you

Comment: Where do you find this `DataGridListView ` control? Can't find any doc about it. But `{Binding Source={StaticResource model}, Path= SelectedItem}` should probably be `{Binding ElementName=myDataGridListView, Path= SelectedItem}`. You want the `SelectedItem` of the `DataGridListView` control.

Answer (score 0):

Without any other information, I am assuming that SelectedItem is a property inside `model`, it does not look like SelectedItem in the StaticResource model is bound to anything. I believe you can try one of two steps.

1. Replace `i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding Source={StaticResource model}, Path= SelectedItem}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource model}, Path=MouseDoubleClickCommand}">` with `i:InvokeCommandAction CommandParameter="{Binding Source={ElementName=PTest, Path=SelectedItem}, Path= SelectedItem}" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource model}, Path=MouseDoubleClickCommand}">`
2. Instead of SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem} on ui:DataGridListView try `SelectedItem={Binding Source={StaticResource model}, Path=SelectedItem}`